# How to multiply AWK output

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file data.csv with multiple lines that reads:

```
A
B
C
```

and I want the output of the code to be multiplied n times:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

Here is an example of a line I've been trying and what it returns:

```
awk '{for (i=0; i<3 ;i++){ print $1}}' input.csv
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

Same with cat and other tools

Comment: Why not "cat" the file 3 times? Do you need it to work with pipes? Are you aware of memory requirements?

Comment: Thanks for you reply! It didn't need to be done with cat, I just learned about awk today and was curious if there was a way using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{ for (i=1;i<n;i++) {ARGV[ARGC]=ARGV[1]; ARGC++} } 1' file
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

Note that the above only stores the **name** of the file `n` times, not the **contents** of the file and so it'd work for any file of any size as it uses negligible memory.

Comment: `ARGV[ARGC++]=ARGV[1]` would work as well wouldn't it ?

Comment: That's what I used to use until someone pointed me to some document that essentially showed the you couldn't guarantee the `ARGC++` wouldn't happen before the assignment. I don't recall if it was the POSIX spec or what but between that and clarity it persuaded me to change to always explicitly put the `ARGC++` after the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This would do:

```
for i in {1..3}; do cat data.csv; done
```

It won't work with pipes, though.

Thanks for the comments

Comment: This is innefficient as it forks cat every time.

Comment: I meant memory efficient, rather than storing the whole chunk in memory. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cat and printf

```
cat $(printf "%0.sfile " {1..3})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single efficient 1-liner:  `yes data | head -3 | xargs cat`

```
$ cat data 
A
B
C
$ yes data | head -3 | xargs cat
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
$
```

`head -3` => here `3` indicates `n` number of times.

Or using an `awk` solution:

```
$ cat data 
A
B
C
$ awk 'BEGIN{i=0} {a[i]=$0;i++} END {for(i=0;i<=3;i++) for(j=0;j<=NR;j++) print a[j]}' data | sed '/^$/d'
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
seq 2 | xargs -Inone cat input.csv
```

Comment: Nice. I was just looking at `xargs` like this and trying to figure out how to get it to ignore the `seq` output.

Answer (score 1):

probably the shortest

```
cat input.csv{,,}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (( c=1; c<=3; c++ ))
do
cat Input_file.csv
done
```

Comment: sorry, my bad. I got the question wrong. will correct it soon.

Comment: corrected as per requirement ,but other ways are better.

Comment: @user2809888 You're asking @monk to explain `cat` called in a loop from 1 to 3???

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you're writing a shell-script, why use awk?

```
for i in `seq 3`; do
  cat data.csv
done
```

If you want to do this using pipes, e.g. with awk, you'll need to store the file data in memory or save it temporarily to disk. For example:

```
cat data.csv | \
  awk '{a = a $0 "\n"} END { for (i=0; i<3 ;i++){ printf "%s",a; }}'
```

Comment: Actually you're right it's easier to do it without using awk with a for loop, I was curious if there was a way since I did not find about it elsewhere. Also I'm a beginner, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

With sed and hold/pattern space:

In this given situation with only single letters. Respectively ABC:

If you want to print once:

```
cat temp | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1/;N;N;H'
```

output:

```
[anthony@aguevara ~]$ cat temp | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1/;N;N;H;G;G'
A
B
C
[anthony@aguevara ~]$
```

Twice(Just append a semi-colon/capital G tot he end):

```
cat temp | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1/;N;N;H;G'
```

output:

```
[anthony@aguevara ~]$ cat temp | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1/;N;N;H;G;G'
A
B
C

A
B
C
[anthony@aguevara ~]$
```

Three times(Another G):

```
cat temp | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1/;N;N;H;G;G'
```

output:

```
[anthony@aguevara ~]$ cat temp | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1/;N;N;H;G;G'
A
B
C

A
B
C

A
B
C
[anthony@aguevara ~]$
```

and so on.

File(Has no newlines in file):

```
[anthony@aguevara ~]$ cat temp
A
B
C
[anthony@aguevara ~]$
```